# Angular JS image display error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have uploaded image in upload table using grids and MongoDB and I have stored image name in store table.

When I get store details first i have taken image name and check from upload table and  displaying the image.

Here I am looping that image name its working but it always showing last image. I have enclosed my html and controller.

```js
$http.get('***').success(function(data,dealers,response) {     
    var storelen=data.length;
    console.log(storelen); 
    for(var i=0;i<storelen;i++) {
        var storeimages=JSON.stringify(data[i].Store_Images);
        var storeimages=(storeimages.replace(/\"/g, ""));
        console.log(storeimages);
        $http.get('***').success(function(data, status,response) { 
            $scope.image=data;
            console.log($scope.image);
        }); 
    }
    $scope.dealers = data;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-view > 
  <ion-content  style="margin-top:50px;" ng-controller="ListingCtrl" data-ng-init="find()">
    <div class="list card"  data-ng-repeat="dealer in dealers |  filter:query |  filter:myFilter">
      <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" href="#">
        <img src="{{image}}" id="myimage"> 
        <h2>{{dealer.Store_Name}}</h2> 
        <p>{{dealer.S_Address.city}}&nbsp;,&nbsp;{{dealer.S_Address.area}}</p> 
        <div class="row" style="padding:0px;">
          <div class="col-90"><p style="font-size:10px">review</p></div>
          <div class="col-10"  style="margin-left:30px;">
            <i style="right:0px;font-size:18px;color:#ff6f00;"class="icon ion-ios-location subdued"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding:0px;">
          <div class="col" style="padding: 0px;"><p style="font-size:14px;" listing-rating rating-value="rating" max="5"></div>  
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
        <a class="tab-item" ng-href="tel:{{dealer.S_Phone.number}}">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone " ></i>
          Contact Now
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item"  style="color:green;">
          <i class="icon ion-pricetags"></i>
          Email
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item"  style="color:#ff6f00;"  >
          <i class="icon ion-wand" ></i>
          Check  Now
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view >
```

In my table having 3 images, I am getting 3 images in console, but html I am always getting the last image.
I want to display image with in ng-repeat is there any other way doing it ?

Comment: it's hard to understand what you are doing since you redacted the entire URL for those get requests, but it seems like what you want is to add the image to the `dealer` object, so you can just do `dealer.image`.  short of that, you would need to use an array of images, and have to keep the array of `images` and the array of `dealers` in sync somehow.  `$scope.image` won't ever work, since that limits you to one image only for the entire scope.

Comment: what i can i do now please give some suggestion to get all images

Comment: asynchronous job (such as "GET") in javascript loop wont work. Beacuse the loop is running from the stack and only when it completes, all the callbacks that are located in the event loop are being executed, thats why you are getting only the last one. i suggest that you get all images in one get (which is better practice from the performance point of view) and then loop over the results